# NSDictionary constant looping

Tags: ios, objective-c, flickr

SO I have a program which calls the FlickR API, gets the URL's puts them into a dictionary and then assigns them into a table view, using an image view.

```
NSArray *photos = [self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"];
    int countAttempts = 0;
    [[self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"]count];
    for (int i = 0; i < [[self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"]count]; i++) {

        for(NSDictionary *dictionary in photos) {
            countAttempts++;

            NSString *farmId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"farm"];
            NSString *serverId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"server"];
            NSString *photoId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *secret = [dictionary objectForKey:@"secret"];

            self.url= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@.jpg", farmId, serverId, photoId, secret]];
            //NSLog(@"self.url = %@", self.url);
            NSLog(@"count = %d", countAttempts);

            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.url];

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                    cell.imageView.image = img;
                    [cell setNeedsLayout];
                });

            });

            }
    }
return cell;
}
```

This is the method it calls, photosForUser:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) photosForUser: (NSString *) friendUserName
{
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.findByUsername&username=%@", friendUserName];
    NSDictionary *result = [self fetch: request];
    NSString *nsid = [result valueForKeyPath: @"user.nsid"];

    request = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=%ld&has_geo=1&user_id=%@&extras=original_format,tags,description,geo,date_upload,owner_name,place_url", (long) self.maximumResults, nsid];

    result = [self fetch: request];
    return [result valueForKeyPath: @"photos.photo"];

}
```

Which does a fetch to the flickr API.

What is happening though is that is stuck in an eternal loop. Even with the for statement being less than the count, it still eternal loops. I have NSLog'd the count of the FlickR photos and it = 11.

This may have something to do with it, but whenever I press the button to take me to the table view controller, I get a HUGE lag, close to a minute, and nothing is being calculated (photo-wise) as I've done a count++

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this statement: `[[self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"]count];`?

Comment: that passes the a string to the photosForUser method, string being the name of the person I am searching.

The count part is just to return the amount of elements that are stored within that, just so I can have an idea

Comment: But what is it's purpose?  You don't use it's result.

Comment: are you referring to the second line? The reason I left it in there was just so I could confirm that my NSDictionary wasn't the issue, and it didn't have thousands of records. 

Should I remove it?

Comment: Why not extract the count into a local variable and use that in your for loop?  Will be faster, plus easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me understand this.. By the last line of your first block of code, I conclude that that is the uitableview dataSource method, cellForRowAtIndexPath.. what doesn't really makes sense.. you you have a fetch there, you have A loop inside a loop, that is setting many images (by download them) in one single imageView, and this is happening for all your visible cells at the same time. This will never work!

The solution is: 
1 - remove this method from the cellForRow, this is not the place to request the images

2 - create another method that will fetch the content

3 - create a method that will do your loops and store the images on the array so you don't need to do that many times, only one..

4 - reload the tableview after you finish the step 3

5 - use the array of images that is already done to set your images by indexPath.row in your cell..

6 - I recommend you to use a Library for imageCache (i.e https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the imageCache now.

But doesn't a seperate method defeat the purpose? Since you will still need to do the loading into the array from the web in the method, and then more loading again? OR is the point of it to break the loading up in half?

Comment: You will not make any load in the array inside the tableview delegate, the array has to be loaded before your tableview is built.. every time one cell is displayed you are requesting an array of pictures from the api.. it should not be like that.. if you move this to another method, you are not going to call this method from the cell.. you should do that from viewDidLoad for example.. The cell will only set the image in the imageView, nothing else!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *photos = [self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"];

for (int i = 0; i < [[self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"] count]; i++)
{
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in photos)
    {
```

You have two nested loops iterating over the same collection. This turns what should be an O(n) operation into O(n^2) and explains why your process is taking a very long time.

Since the loop bodies never use `i`, I would fix it by getting rid of the outer loop:

```
NSArray *photos = [self.flickr photosForUser:@"James Kinvig"];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in photos)
{
```

Comment: I only implemented the for (int i) loop after the constant looping, and it didn't seem to fix the problem. Do you have any other ideas what it could be?? Thanks